# Unable to install Korean acupuncture app on S22 Ultra due to compatibility

Tags: android-studio, build-error

Application statements that are incompatible with your device

I downloaded a Korean acupuncture app from GitHub, and when I modified the gradle version and set up the ndk to run it, I got the error

> Your device is not compatible with this version

I will upload various files such as build.gradle and local.properties, so I would like to ask if you can take a look at the error.

When I run the emulator within Android Studio, it runs, but when I move it to APK, it says it's not compatible and won't install.

The material on GitHub is from 2014, and my phone model is S22 ULTRA, and it doesn't run even if I set Sdkversion to 29 or 33.

app.build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')
}
```

opencv.build.gradle

```
// This file is part of OpenCV project.
// It is subject to the license terms in the LICENSE file found in the top-level directory
// of this distribution and at http://opencv.org/license.html.

//
// Notes about integration OpenCV into existed Android Studio application project are below (application 'app' module should exist).
//
// This file is located in <OpenCV-android-sdk>/sdk directory (near 'etc', 'java', 'native' subdirectories)
//
// Add module into Android Studio application project:
//
// - Android Studio way:
//   (will copy almost all OpenCV Android SDK into your project, ~200Mb)
//
//   Import module: Menu -> "File" -> "New" -> "Module" -> "Import Gradle project":
//   Source directory: select this "sdk" directory
//   Module name: ":opencv"
//
// - or attach library module from OpenCV Android SDK
//   (without copying into application project directory, allow to share the same module between projects)
//
//   Edit "settings.gradle" and add these lines:
//
//   def opencvsdk='<path_to_opencv_android_sdk_rootdir>'
//   // You can put declaration above into gradle.properties file instead (including file in HOME directory),
//   // but without 'def' and apostrophe symbols ('): opencvsdk=<path_to_opencv_android_sdk_rootdir>
//   include ':opencv'
//   project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
//
//
//
// Add dependency into application module:
//
// - Android Studio way:
//   "Open Module Settings" (F4) -> "Dependencies" tab
//
// - or add "project(':opencv')" dependency into app/build.gradle:
//
//   dependencies {
//       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//       ...
//       implementation project(':opencv')
//   }
//
//
//
// Load OpenCV native library before using:
//
// - avoid using of "OpenCVLoader.initAsync()" approach - it is deprecated
//   It may load library with different version (from OpenCV Android Manager, which is installed separately on device)
//
// - use "System.loadLibrary("opencv_java4")" or "OpenCVLoader.initDebug()"
//   TODO: Add accurate API to load OpenCV native library
//
//
//
// Native C++ support (necessary to use OpenCV in native code of application only):
//
// - Use find_package() in app/CMakeLists.txt:
//
//   find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED java)
//   ...
//   target_link_libraries(native-lib ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
//
// - Add "OpenCV_DIR" and enable C++ exceptions/RTTI support via app/build.gradle
//   Documentation about CMake options: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html
//
//   defaultConfig {
//       ...
//       externalNativeBuild {
//           cmake {
//               cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
//               arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + opencvsdk + "/sdk/native/jni" // , "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
//           }
//       }
//   }
//
// - (optional) Limit/filter ABIs to build ('android' scope of 'app/build.gradle'):
//   Useful information: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html (Configure separate APKs per ABI)
//
//   splits {
//       abi {
//           enable true
//           universalApk false
//           reset()
//           include 'armeabi-v7a' // , 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
//       }
//   }
//

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

println "OpenCV: " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //buildToolsVersion "x.y.z" // not needed since com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
            java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"  android:required="false"/>



    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/splash_image"
        android:label="@string/label_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/splashTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".six_list" />
        <activity android:name=".five_list" />
        <activity android:name=".four_list" />
        <activity android:name=".three_list" />
        <activity android:name=".two_list" />
        <activity android:name=".one_head" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapplication"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".Camera"
            android:theme="@style/splashTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".setting" />
        <activity android:name=".pain_choice" />
        <activity android:name=".suji_info" />
        <activity android:name=".Log" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```